# My OS X app slowly consumes more and more ram over time, how can I debug this and find the cause?

Tags: macos, memory-leaks

I am new to swift and coding in general. I have made my first OS X app over the last few days. It is a simple ticker app that lives in the menu bar.

My issue is that over the space of 3 hours, my app goes from 10mb or ram being used to over 1gb. It slowly and slowly uses more and more. I noticed after about 6 hours the app stops working, I can only assume that OS X has stopped the process because it's hogging too much memory?

Anyway, I have looked online and I have used Xcode instruments to try and find a memory leak, but I don't know exactly how to pin point it. Can anyone give me some general good ways to find memory leaks and sources of bugs when using Xcode? Any general practices are good too.

Comment: Use Instruments to find memory leaks and/or reference cycles.

Comment: DanTdd, my guess is that the leak has something to do with the timer you were asking about the other day...

Comment: Hey @nhgrif, it must have something to do with that. It seems to be working fine but I can't find what would be causing it :(

Answer (score 5):

If the memory loss is not due to a leak (Run Leaks and Analyzer) the lost is to inadvertently retained and unused memory.

Use instruments to check for leaks and memory loss due to retained but not leaked memory. The latter is unused memory that is still pointed to. Use Mark Generation (Heapshot) in the Allocations instrument on Instruments.

For HowTo use Heapshot to find memory creap, see: [bbum blog](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/)

Basically the method is to run Instruments allocate tool, take a heapshot, run an iteration of your code and take another heapshot repeating 3 or 4 times. This will indicate memory that is allocated and not released during the iterations.

To figure out the results disclose to see the individual allocations.

If you need to see where retains, releases and autoreleases occur for an object use instruments:

Run in instruments, in Allocations set "Record reference counts" on (For Xcode 5 and lower you have to stop recording to set the option). Cause the app to run, stop recording, drill down and you will be able to see where all retains, releases and autoreleases occurred.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer Zaph. I can see that there [are](http://i.imgur.com/zDhGfDI.png) a few processes taking up lots of memory.

Answer (score 0):

When confronted with a memory leak, the first thing I do is look at where variables are created and destroyed; especially if they are defined in looping logic (although generally not a good idea).

Generally most memory leaks come from there. I would venture a guess that the leak occurs somewhere in the logic that tracks your timed iterations.

Good luck!